# How can I change a folder background in windows?

Tags: c#, registry, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I run into this program:

http://www.door2windows.com/windows-7-folder-background-changer-change-any-folders-background-text-color-in-windows-7vista/

Im looking for the same solution

Tried and tried continuously to find any information on how to do this online, does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

on xp:

Copy the code below into notepad and then save it as "desktop.ini" make it hidden and make the current folder as system folder .

```
[.ShellClassInfo]    
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll    
IconIndex=127    
ConfirmFileOp=0    

[{BE098140-A513-11D0-A3A4-00C04FD706EC}]    
Attributes=1    
IconArea_Image="your_picture.jpg"    
IconArea_Text="0xFFFFFF"    
VeBRA sources - don't delete the tag above, it's there for XXXXX purposes -    
[ExtShellFolderViews]    
{BE098140-A513-11D0-A3A4-00C04FD706EC}={BE098140-A513-11D0-A3A4-00C04FD706EC}    
{5984FFE0-28D4-11CF-AE66-08002B2E1262}={5984FFE0-28D4-11CF-AE66-08002B2E1262}    

[{5984FFE0-28D4-11CF-AE66-08002B2E1262}]    
PersistMoniker=Folder.htt    
PersistMonikerPreview=%WebDir%\folder.bmp
```

but how about win 7/ vista?

Comment: This is not answer to your question.

Comment: I don't understand the argument, this supply a complete solution for win xp thus answering the question

Comment: This is not how to change background via shell extension as you ask!